# Accessing kubernetes running inside docker in a guest OS from the host OS

Tags: docker, vagrant, kubernetes

I'm trying to access the kubernetes api exposed inside a guest OS provisionned by Vagrant from the host OS. The Vagrantfile exposes all ports of the guest OS through a private network and also forward the port 8080 like this :

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

When following the [kubernetes getting started guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html) with docker, I can't access the kubernetes api from the **host OS** through :

- http://127.0.0.1:8080
- http://192.168.50.4:8080

but the api are accessible from the **guest OS** at http://127.0.0.1:8080 only...

When running nginx from the guest OS like this

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

the nginx server is accessible from the **host OS** at both http://127.0.0.1:8080 and http://192.168.50.4:8080

I'm wondering how what parameter is missing from the getting started guide to run kubernetes in docker and access it from the **host OS** through the private network setup wih vagrant (just like nginx) ?

Comment: might be the --net=host docker option ?

Comment: is it not just the -p required to redirect ports?

Comment: no, it's not, it is accessible from the guest os...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an ExternalIP per the services spec at http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#external-ips

When configuring your service you'll want to include a section with something like the following (in JSON, you may prefer yaml).

`{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "MyApp"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 8080,
                "targetPort": 8080
            }
        ],
        "externalIPs" : [
            192.168.50.4"
        ]
    }
}`